# Python fork(): passing data from child to parent

Tags: python, numpy, fork, shared-memory, large-data

I have a main Python process, and a bunch or workers created by the main process using [`os.fork()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.fork).

I need to pass large and fairly involved data structures from the workers back to the main process. What existing libraries would you recommend for that?

The data structures are a mix of lists, dictionaries, [`numpy` arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html), custom classes (which I can tweak) and multi-layer combinations of the above.

Disk I/O should be avoided. If I could also avoid creating copies of the data -- for example by having some kind of shared-memory solution -- that would be nice too, but is not a hard constraint.

For the purposes of this question, it is mandatory that the workers are created using `os.fork()`, or a wrapper thereof that would clone the master process's address space.

This only needs to work on Linux.

Comment: "Disk I/O should be avoided." I assume that doesn't include paging, in situations where the amount of data in memory grows large enough that paging would be needed.

Comment: @JAB: Your assumption is correct. However, the eventual solution should make judicious use of memory.

Answer (score 4):

`multiprocessing`'s queue implementation works. Internally, it pickles data to a pipe.

```
q = multiprocessing.Queue()
if (os.fork() == 0):
    print(q.get())
else:
    q.put(5)
# outputs: 5
```